Transform binary response to pdf in expressjs
I'm trying to use the Browserless PDF API, and for this I wrote the following code:
// my server located on localhost:3000
app.get("/api/pdf", async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/pdf", {
            url: "https://www.google.com/",
        })

        response.setHeader("content-type", "application/pdf")
        response.contentType("application/pdf")
        response.send(Buffer.from(data, "binary"))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})

in browser its look like this:

but if I fulfill the equal curl request
// Browserless API located on localhost:3001
curl -X POST  \
  http://localhost:3001/pdf \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "url": "https://google.com/"
}'  --output 'file.pdf'


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 49148    0 49114  100    34  38039     26  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 38040

its look like this

what's wrong with my code?
Minimal reproducible example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-hw2mex?file=index.js

browser render empty pdf, on route "/api/pdf"

no, my server is located at localhost:3000/api/pdf
The Browserless PDF API is located at http://localhost:3001/pdf

this will download a zero KB PDF file

I noticed this too now and it's really weird

there is no error in the console

nothing has changed =(

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The browser is making a GET request but your curl example uses POST which clearly isn't handled by app.get("/api/pdf", ...)

It's two different servers. On port 3000 I have an own server (u can see a code in question). On port 3001 I have a Browserless PDF API

Why don't you curl the server instead of the PDF api?? That way you compare apples with apples. This might allow you to see better where to problem lies. You could also check the PDF API with the browser. You'd be able to pin point where the problems lies.

I'm should to add responseType: "arraybuffer" in axios.post config object
app.get("/api/pdf", async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3001/pdf",
            {
                url: "https://www.google.com/",
            },
            {
                responseType: "arraybuffer",
            },
        )

        response.setHeader("content-type", "application/pdf")
        response.contentType("application/pdf")
        response.send(Buffer.from(data, "binary"))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})

PS: Thanks @Jaromanda X for investigation
